# Obtener dirección a partir de latitud y longitud en Ionic 1

Tags: ionic

Quiero obtener una dirección mediante latitud y longitud obtenida.

la funcion que uso par aobtenr latidud y longitud es las siguiente:

```
 $scope.getLocation = function(){
    var posOptions = {
        timeout: 10000,
        enableHighAccuracy: false
    };
    $cordovaGeolocation
        .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
        .then(function (position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            $rootScope.position_order = lat + "," + long;
            console.log(position);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);

            $rootScope.position_order = null;
        });
};
```

Investigando encontré que existe un plugin par Ionic  llamado Native Geocoder (aunque no se si sera compatible con Ionic 1)

esta funcion utiliza dicho plugin:

```
let options: NativeGeocoderOptions = {
useLocale: true,
maxResults: 5
};

this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(52.5072095, 13.1452818, options)
.then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult[]) => 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0])))
 .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));

this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode('Berlin', options)
.then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult[]) => console.log('The 
 coordinates are latitude=' + coordinates[0].latitude + ' and 
 longitude=' + coordinates[0].longitude))
  .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

Como puedo transformar esa función de Ionic 4 a Ionic 1 para obtener una dirección a partir de lat y long.

Comment: Debes usar la version para Ionic 1
[Mira aqui](https://github.com/sebastianbaar/cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder)

Comment: Puedes hacer un llamado a la api de google maps específicamente la que sirve para hacer __geocodifición__ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro la versión de ionic que uses no importa en este caso